# Bootstrap File Input Plugin

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

Alguém já usou esse [Bootstrap File Input Plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) com PHP? Ou seja, fazendo insert de imagens no banco? 
Estou com dificuldade em pegar os arquivos do "plugin" e não do input file, para fazer a persistência.

Código

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="imagensSitio">
     <input id="file-0a" class="file" type="file" name="img[]" multiple="true" >
     <input type="submit" name="salvar" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#imagensSitio').submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "crud/insere.php", // Url to which the request is sending
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});

$("#file-0a").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "crud/insere.php",
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 10,
    showUpload:true,
    showRemove:true
});
</script>
```

Insere.php

```
 include("../../../resources/conexao/conexao.php");
require ("../../../resources/wideImage/WideImage.php"); 

$nomeImg = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$nomeTmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];  

$extensao = array(".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png");

$dir_imagem = '../imagens/sitio/';

for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeTmp); $i++) {

    $extensao_img = strtolower(substr($nomeImg[$i],-4));

    if(in_array($extensao_img, $extensao)) {

        $novo_nome_imagem = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") ."-". $i . $extensao_img;

        $imagem = WideImage::load($nomeTmp[$i]);
        $imagem = $imagem -> resize(770, 550, 'outside');

        if ($extensao_img == ".jpg" || $extensao_img == ".jpeg"){
            $imagem -> saveToFile($dir_imagem.$novo_nome_imagem, 85);
        } else if ($extensao_img == ".png") {
            $imagem -> saveToFile($dir_imagem.$novo_nome_imagem, 9);
        }

        $insert = "INSERT INTO sitio(imagem) VALUES ('$novo_nome_imagem')"; 
        $conexao = conexao();
        $PDO = $conexao->prepare($insert);
        $PDO -> execute();
        $conexao = null;                
    } 
}
```

Print página

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque o código que você esta usando e qual o retorno esta tendo...

Comment: Não, eu simplesmente faço da forma normal, pegando as imagens no input file. Se você conhece o plugin, após  eu escolher as imagens, e caso excluir uma delas, antes de enviar para o banco, ele considera as imagens do input file, não as do "plugin", entende?

Comment: qual exatamente sua dúvida?
Para pegar os arquivos deste plugin em javascript eu pegava os elementos do próprio `input type="file"` com `document.getElementById("input").files`

Comment: se você quer pegar as imagens do plugin e inserir/alterar no banco de dados o proprio plugin ja disponibiliza na documentação o `how to` usando jquery.

Comment: certo, e usando PHP?

Comment: @Alisson quando você tenta pegar o array de files direto do input type file com o php não está vindo os arquivos que você subiu pelo plugin? para pegar os arquivos é da mesma forma que se pega de um file Input normal.

Comment: Quando faço a exclusão de um arquivo no plugin, na hora de inserir o array vem vazio, ou seja, como se não tivesse arquivo. Ah, faço o insert com ajax. Deduzi que não seria a forma correta de pegar normalmente do file input...

Comment: @Alisson eu particularmente não vejo problema nenhum pegar do file input, o próprio plugin insere os arquivos no file input quando se faz um upload e remove também, portanto está sempre de acordo com o plugin.
Eles apenas criaram o "visual" para o file input. Comigo pelo menos nunca deu problema nenhum.

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior Editei o tópico com o código fonte, veja. Peguei o exemplo em um blog, porém não rola, a partir do momento que faço a exclusão de uma foto, e dou submit, ele não cadastrada ao banco, ou seja, o array de imagens input file provavelmente está vazio. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @Alisson o seu problema é que você quer deletar uma foto do banco por este plugin, dando um post de um array vazio?

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior Não, quero pegar imagens do computador e inserir o nome da imagem no banco, normal, como um crud simples de imagens. Pórem com esse plugin que estou com dificuldade de fazer isso. Por exemplo quando pego as imagens e excluo uma e após mando inserir o restante no banco.

Comment: @Alisson, realmente o plugin tem algumas funcionalidades que ele deixa de usar apenas o input type file e utiliza de outras maneiras, pelo o que eu vi o da qual você está usando, realmente não da para usar o próprio input, fiz uns testes aqui usando a própria propriedade `uploadUrl` do plugin, sempre usei o `basic usage` deste plugin, então nunca precisei recorrer à outros métodos, de uma olhada no que eles mesmos falam sobre o upload em AJAX, `http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-uploads`, infelizmente não sei sua resposta, teria que dar uma pesquisada. depois irei dar outra olhada.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada no que você passou, se você tiver alguma novidade depois, compartilha aqui. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.serialize() você não vai conseguir pegar as informações do upload.
Tente usar o plugin [ajaxform](http://malsup.com/jquery/form)

Um exemplo do meu upload com jquery:

```
$('#enviar').click(function (Event) {
        Event.preventDefault();
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';

        $('#frm').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: base_url + 'local/inserir',
            resetForm: true,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.resultado === true) {
                    $('.titulo').html('<h3>Cadastro realizado</h3>');
                    $('.mensagem').html(response.mensagem);
                    $('.modal-content').addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $('.modal').modal();
                } else {
                    $('.titulo').html('<h3>AtenÃ§Ã£o!</h3>');
                    $('.mensagem').html('NÃ£o foi possível cadastrar o projeto<br><hr>' + response.mensagem);
                    $('.modal-content').addClass('alert alert-warning');
                    $('.modal').modal();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.titulo').html('<h3>Atenção!</h3>');
                $('.mensagem').html('NÃ£o foi possível cadastrar o projeto<br><hr>' + response.mensagem);
                $('.modal-content').addClass('alert alert-warning');
                $('.modal').modal();
            }
        }).submit();
    })
```

OBS: onde esta url: base_url + 'local/inserir', você deve colocar a pagina que você vai chamar.